# Understanding the difference between a 2D texture array and a 3D texture?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

If I understand correctly, if I was to set `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `NEAREST` then there's not much difference between `sampler2DArray`/`TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY` and `sampler3D`/`TEXTURE_3D`

The differences seem to be

- `GenerateMipmap` will blend cross layers with 3D textures but not 2D arrays
- the `Z` coordinate passed to `texture` in GLSL is 0 to 1 with 3D textures but an 0 to N (depth) in 2D arrays.
- If filtering is not NEAREST 3D will blend across layers, 2D array will not.

Correct?

Answer (score 12):

Incorrect. There's one more difference: mipmap sizes.

In a 3D texture, the width, height, and depth all decrease at lower mipmap sizes. In a 2D array texture, every mipmap level has the *same* number of array layers; only width and height decrease.

It's not just a matter of blending and some texture coordinate oddities; the very size of the texture data is different. It is very much a different *kind* of texture, as different from 3D textures as 2D textures are from 1D textures.

This is also why you cannot create a [view texture](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Texture_views) of a 3D texture that is a 2D array, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 11):

Apart from the answer already given, there is another difference worth noting: The size limits are also quite different. A single layer of an array texture  may be as big as an standard 2D texture, and there is an extra limit on the number of layers, while for 3D textures, there is a limit constraining the maximum size in all dimensions.

For example, [OpenGL 4.5](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec45.core.pdf) guarantees the following minimal values:

```
GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE           16384
GL_MAX_ARRAY_TEXTURE_LAYERS   2048
GL_MAX_3D_TEXTURE_SIZE        2048
```

So a 16384 x 16384 x 16 array texture is fine (and should also fit into memory for every GL 4.5 capable GPU found in the real world), while a 3D texture of the same dimensions would be unsupported on most of todays implementations (even though the complete mipmap pyramid would consume *less* memory in the 3D texture case).