# GL_TEXTURE_3D - mipmaps dimensions

Tags: opengl

When I load a GL_TEXTURE_2D (512x256) mipmaps are defined this way:

- level 0: 512 x 256
- level 1: 256 x 128
- level 2: 128 x 64
- level 3: 64 x 32
- level 4: 32 x 16
- level 5: 16 x 8
- level 6: 8 x 4
- level 7: 4 x 2
- level 8: 2 x 1
- level 9: 1 x 1

I can load all mipmaps manually using glTexImage2D. How mipmaps are defined for GL_TEXTURE_3D, for example (512 x 256 x 4) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are defined in exactly the same way as a 2D texture: take each dimension and divide by 2 (rounded down), and keep going until all dimensions are 1.

Comment: What about GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY ?

Comment: @Irbis: A 2D [array texture](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Array_Texture) contains 2D images. Therefore, only [two dimensions scale with its mipmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35818027/734069).