# Create texture array

Tags: opengl, texture2d

I create a texture array as follows:

```java
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, textureID);

    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
        // ... expected parameters
    );

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0); // unbind
```

This works fine and I have no issues with it (at least for now).

I wondered why I have to bind to a `GL_TEXTURE_3D` and just tried and replaced it with a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY`, like so:

```java
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, textureID);

    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,
        // ... expected parameters
    );

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0); // unbind
```

This works, too. I'm kind of confused why, because I expected there to be only one correct way and to have error messages in other cases.

The texture array actually contains just one texture and I'm concerned that ugly errors may arise when I finally add more than just one texture to the array.

Which of those two is correct? Or are they both valid? In that case, which is *better* if I'm just interested in a *discrete list* of 2D textures, and **not** a 3D texture with a continuous (float) Z coordinate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35818027/understanding-the-difference-between-a-2d-texture-array-and-a-3d-texture Does this help?

Comment: Thanks @matt, it helps a bit. But I'm still uncertain if Z will be `[0, 1]` or `0..N` in the first example where I bind to the GL_TEXTURE_3D.

Comment: @pid: The other question literally says, "the Z coordinate passed to texture in GLSL is 0 to 1 with 3D textures but an 0 to N (depth) in 2D arrays." What part of that leaves you in any way uncertain?

Comment: The answer to the other question is pretty clear. My uncertainty came from the online material I used initially, where their code example shows `GL_TEXTURE_3D` to allocate a *texture array*. Now I'm not uncertain anymore! Thanks matt and NicolBolas!

Comment: @NicolBolas BTW, off topic, learning Rust + Vulkan at the same time was a bit too much for me. Now I'm trying to create some ground knowledge in an easier way, with Java + LWJGL + OpenGL. And I must admit it's WAY easier to understand and use, despite obvious performance loss which is not a real concern right now.